# Hibernate e JPA são a mesma coisa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

É uma pergunta de quem acabou de pegar esse assunto pra estudar porém me confunde bastante. Li alguns artigos sobre ORM e não entendi muito bem o que é um e o que é o outro, são a mesma coisa? da pra usar um sem o outro? Onde cada um se distingue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hibernate é uma tecnologia, ela foi a primeira tecnlogia de ORM para Java. Com a popularização da mesma a Oracle (empresa mantenedora do Java na época) acabou por convidar os criadores do Hibernate para construírem o JPA que é uma espeficicação indicando como deve ser implementado qualquer framework ORM para padronizar a forma com o desenvolvedor final trabalha com eles.

Além do Hibernate um outro framework de JPA é o EclipseLink.

---

O relacionamento entre elas seria assim:

- O JPA é uma especificação que define uma interface comum para os frameworks ORM;
- O Hibernate é um framework que implementa JPA;
- O EclipseLink é outro framework que também implementa JPA sendo assim concorrente do Hibernate.

Answer (score 4):

JPA é apenas uma especificação, não há implementação. Pense no JPA como um conjunto de diretrizes que devem ser seguidas na implementação.

Hibernate é uma das implementações que segue essas diretrizes. Um dos benefícios de se utilizar JPA é a possibilidade de trocar de implementação, pois todas usam a mesma interface. Existem outras implementações além do Hibernate, como EclipseLink e TopLink.

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9881640/5360385)

Answer (score 2):

Não são. Esta é uma dúvida muito comum, que inclusive já tive nos meus primeiros anos de desenvolvimento com Hibernate.

**JPA** significa *Java Persistence API*. É uma [especificação](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=java%20persistence) de uma "API Java para gerenciamento de persistência e mapeamento objeto/relacional em ambientes Java EE e Java SE".

Basicamente, o JPA une um conjunto de regras que permite que qualquer um possa implementar esta API, permitindo que possa usar esta implementação em qualquer projeto que utilize as interfaces JPA, garantindo assim uma certa compatibilidade entre diferentes implementações.

É aqui que entra o **Hibernate**. O Hibernate é uma implementação da especificação JPA, certamente a mais comum e usada. Além do Hibernate, temos também outras implementações do JPA, como o [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org) e [EclipseLink](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/). É comum muitas pessoas tratarem Hibernate e JPA como se fossem uma coisa só, tanto que é comum você ter uma dúvida específica de JPA mas encontrar a resposta em uma pergunta que só cita o Hibernate nela. Esta confusão só existe por causa da popularidade maior do Hibernate.

Em teoria, se não estiver usando nenhum recurso exclusivo de alguma implementação (o que é relativamente comum), é possível trocar uma implementação por outra no seu projeto de forma transparente. Por exemplo, um mapeamento comum de entidade envolve [anotações](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations) como `@Column`, `@Table`, `@Id`, etc, e todos eles fazem parte do pacote `javax.persistence`, comum a qualquer implementação JPA. Assim, uma troca do Hibernate pelo OpenJPA (por exemplo) ocorreria de forma transparente para a aplicação.